# The second do while loop in this code. I need somebody to explain what it is actually doing in more simple terms

Tags: java, do-while

The second do while loop in this code:

```
do {
  ignore = (char) System.in.read();
} while(ignore != '\n');
```

I cannot comprehend what it actually does. All I understand is that when I take it out and run the program and guess an incorrect letter, program will print out 3 lines of the text *"Guess letter now"*. Why does it do that 3 times without that code in place. What does that code even do? So I am confused and just cannot work it out.

```
public class GuessChar {

    public static void main(String args[])
    throws java.io.IOException {

        char ch ,ignore, answer = 'k';

        do {
            System.out.println("Guess the letter now");
            ch = (char) System.in.read();   
            do {
               ignore = (char) System.in.read();
            } while(ignore != '\n');

            if(ch == answer) System.out.println("WELL DONE");

        } while(ch != answer);
    }
}
```

Comment: `'\n'` is the new line character, you ignore all the chars until you find a new line.

Comment: I think it is trying to read characters until a new line (\n) (probally an enter) is presented

Comment: as a whole, this function reads a line of input but only stores the first letter -- all other input on the line is discarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First look at the most confusing part:

```java
char ignore;
do {
    ignore = (char) System.in.read();  // (1)
} while (ignore != '\n');  // (2)
```

The `do` loop is entered unconditionally, so the line marked (1) is always executed.  What it does is reading a single character from the standard input stream and assign the 16 least significant bits (thanks to the typecast) to the variable `ignore`.  It is confusing letters in Java are actually of type `int` but as long as you are only dealing with simple-enough letters (eg symbols from the ASCII character set) they are the same.

The line marked (2) checks whether the just-read character is different from the newline character `\n`.  If so, it will re-enter the loop and break it otherwise.

In combination, this discards any input up to and including the next newline character (ie the end of the current line).

Before that loop, you are also reading in a single character and store it away in the variable `ch`.

```
char ch = (char) System.in.read();
```

After the loop has discarded any remaining characters on the line, you test whether `ch` (that is, the first character that was on the line) is equal to `answer` and, if so, exit or otherwise start anew.

In conclusion, the program reads, line-by-line, input from the user (prompting for each line) until the user enters something that starts with the letter `k`.

Now we have clarified what the program does, let's see how we can improve it.  It turns out that reading one character at a time is very inefficient and there are already methods in the standard library that will do a better job.  Using them and more expressive variable names, the intent of the program becomes much clearer.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class GuessChar {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        char expected = 'k';
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Guess the letter now.");
        while (true) {
            String line = stdin.readLine();
            if (line == null) {  // end of input
                System.out.println("Giving up, eh?");
                break;
            } else if (line.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Sorry, that was no input at all.");
            } else if (line.charAt(0) == expected) {
                System.out.println("Well done!");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Sorry, please try again.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great and detailed answer, although the program improvement part is way beyond me at this stage, thanks for taking the time to write it out.

Answer (score 0):

`'\n'` is a character for "new line", meaning it waits for a user to press "Enter". So second loop will exit as soon as user press Enter, and will check for correct answer afterwards. If answer is wrong, all start from the beginning.